# Why won't my horde spawn at this Ordu?

Tags: humankind

Why can't I spawn my Hunnic horde at this Ordu? It's complaining about a lack of a spawn point, but none of my other Ordus seem to have this problem? Is it maybe because it's on the border?

[image: Why can't I spawn here?]

Comment: I haven't played with the huns so I don't quite know - but I know that it will tell you that you need an appropriate spawn point if the assigned spawn point is full of units

Comment: @n_plum - that much makes sense, but there is actually no other units even in the region.

Comment: Are hordes different where an outpost can behave as a spawn point? Typically you have a little icon of a person with a sword where your spawn point is possible/set to

Comment: @n_plum - hordes are a unique mechanism for Huns and Mongols in that you can spawn a full army of them on an outpost (called an Ordu for the Huns and an Orda for the Mongols) so long as you have a population of 4 and enough influence (which I do have in the screenshot above). This is their Emblematic quarter. Or rather it's instead of an Emblematic quarter.

Comment: Interesting, not sure then. I'm not seeing any listed known bugs in their current threads either